# Action Bar New Back Button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat

In the lastest version of some apps like '`Foursquare`', '`Facebook`', '`Facebook Messenger`', etc.. the back button has an aspect like this

[image: Action Bar Fig. 1]

and when you hover this back button it looks like this:

[image: Action Bar Fig. 2]

This functionality is on the Library Support? How can i add this to my `ActionBar`?

Comment: Its default functionality (Android 4.1+), Refer online doc provided here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: you can try using selector

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i just read the training documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For apps above HoneyComb you can get this inbuilt feature of actionbar by adding following in oncreate method,

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```